# How to use a string of indices to extract rows from dataframe or matrix in R

Tags: r

I have the following string: `"1,34:36,52:58,22:28,82:88,101:102,104:153,120:254,315:368,489:nrow(df)"`. Is there some way of using this string to extract the rows of a dataframe (`df`) that correspond to the numbers in the string.

I've tried using combinations of `eval` and `get` but these don't work and doubt they are the correct route.

Example dataframe:

```
df <- as.data.frame( matrix(rnorm(5000), nrow=500,ncol=10) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of `eval` and `parse`:

```
df <- as.data.frame( matrix(rnorm(5000), nrow=500,ncol=10) )
a <- "1,34:36,52:58,22:28,82:88,101:102,104:153,120:254,315:368,489:nrow(df)"

index <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(a, ",")[[1]], function(x)eval(parse(text=x))))
index
#  [1]   1  34  35  36  52  53  54 ...
#[253] .... 494 495 496 497 498 499 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution since you "know" the name of the dataframe ('df' is already used in the string you have provided)

```
df=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5000), nrow=500,ncol=10))
select_string="1,34:36,52:58,22:28,82:88,101:102,104:153,120:254,315:368,489:nrow(df)"
select_string_total=paste("df[c(",select_string,"),,drop=FALSE]",sep="")
eval(parse(text=select_string_total))
```